# How to reset radio buttons in formik using useformik resetForm or handleReset functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, formik

I have a form which i want my inputs be cleared after a success submit,useFormik handleReset or `useformik.resetForm()` works fine on the text type inputs,but the radio buttons are still remain checked,is there any way i can solve this problem without using state for each radio?
Here is hte code:

```
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import logo from "../images/logoRedBig.jpg";
import axios from 'axios'
import Modal from '../components/CustomModal'
import { useState } from 'react';

function Bform() {
    const [successOpen,setSuccessOpen] = useState(false)
    const [errorOpen,setErrorOpen] = useState(false)
    const [check,setCheck] = useState(false)
    const submitHandler = async (values) => {
            formik.resetForm()
    };
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues:{
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            city:'',
            age:'',
            phone:'',
            occupation:'',
            yearsOfService:'',
            cityOfService:'',
            desiredCity:'',
            currentCompany:'',
            avgCurrSalary:'',
            type:'',
            aboutYou:''
        },
        onSubmit: (values) => submitHandler(values),
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            firstName: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید").required("* نام الزامیست الزامیست"),
            lastName: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید").required("* نام خانوادگی الزامیست"),
            occupation: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید").required("* شغل فعلی الزامیست"),
            city: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید"),
            cityOfService: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید"),
            desiredCity: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید").required("* شهر مد نظر الزامیست"),
            currentCompany: Yup.string().matches(/[آ-ی]/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید"),
            aboutYou: Yup.string().matches(/^[ آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیئ?u06F0-\u06F0-9\s]+$/, "*  فارسی وارد کنید"),
            yearsOfService: Yup.string().matches(/([u06F0-\u06F1-9])/, "*  عدد وارد کنید"),
            age: Yup.string().matches(/([0-9])/,"الگو اشتباه است").required("* سن الزامیست"),
            avgCurrSalary: Yup.string().matches(/([1-9])/,"  عدد وارد کنید"),
            phone: Yup.string().matches(/^([u06F0-\u06F0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/,"* الگو اشتباه است")
            .required("* شماره همراه الزامیست").min(10,"* حداقل باید 10 رقم وارد شود"),
        })
    })
    


  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        {successOpen ? <Modal isOpen={successOpen} onClose={()=>setSuccessOpen(!successOpen)}>
            <h2 className='font-semibold text-green-600'> درخواست همکاری شما با موفقیت ثبت شد</h2>
        </Modal> : null}
        {errorOpen ? <Modal isOpen={errorOpen} onClose={()=>{setErrorOpen(!errorOpen)}}>
            <h2 className='font-semibold text-red-600'> !متاسفانه ثبت اطلاعات شما با مشکل مواجه شد</h2>
        </Modal> : null}
        <div className='grid  text-lg font-bold
                        lg:grid-flow-col lg:py-2
                        xl:flex xl:justify-around xl:gap-5 '>
            <div className='grid gap-5
                            lg:col-span-1 lg:pl-5 lg:max-4xl:border-l lg:max-4xl:border-gray-500 xl:max-4xl:font-normal
                            xl:w-full'>
                <h1 className="text-lg font-extrabold">
                    فرم دریافت نمایندگی
                </h1>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center font-bold
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center xl:max-4xl:font-normal'>
                    <label>
                        نام:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2 w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='firstName'
                        id='firstName'
                        placeholder='نام '
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('firstName')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.firstName ?(formik.errors.firstName ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.firstName}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        نام خانوادگی:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1  ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='lastName'
                        id='lastName'
                        placeholder='نام خانوادگی'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('lastName')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.lastName ?(formik.errors.lastName ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.lastName}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        شهر محل سکونت:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='city'
                        id='city'
                        placeholder='شهر محل سکونت'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('city')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.city ?(formik.errors.city ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.city}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        سن:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='age'
                        id='age'
                        placeholder='سن'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('age')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.age ?(formik.errors.age ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.age}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        تلفن همراه:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='phone'
                        id='phone'
                        placeholder='09xxxxxxxxx'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('phone')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.phone ?(formik.errors.phone ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.phone}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        شغل فعلی:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='occupation'
                        id='occupation'
                        placeholder='شغل فعلی  '
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('occupation')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.occupation ?(formik.errors.occupation ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.occupation}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        سابقه فعالیت:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='yearsOfService'
                        id='yearsOfService'
                        placeholder='سابقه فعالیت  '
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('yearsOfService')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.yearsOfService ?(formik.errors.yearsOfService ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.yearsOfService}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        شهر محل فعالیت:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full md:text-center
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='cityOfService'
                        id='cityOfService'
                        placeholder='شهر محل فعالیت  '
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('cityOfService')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.cityOfService ?(formik.errors.cityOfService ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.cityOfService}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        شهر مد نظر جهت اخذ نمایندگی:
                    </label>
                    {formik.touched.city ?(formik.errors.city ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.city}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                    md:w-full md:text-center
                                    xl:w-8/12
                                    3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='desiredCity'
                        id='desiredCity'
                        placeholder='شهر مد نظر جهت اخذ نمایندگی'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('desiredCity')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.desiredCity ?(formik.errors.desiredCity ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.desiredCity}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        نام مجموعه فعلی:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                    className='block rounded-md w-full ring-1 py-2  ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                 md:w-full md:text-center
                                 xl:w-8/12
                                 3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='currentCompany'
                        id='currentCompany'
                        placeholder='مجموعه فعلی'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('currentCompany')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.currentCompany ?(formik.errors.currentCompany ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.currentCompany}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        متوسط درآمد ماهیانه فعلی:
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        className='block rounded-md py-2  w-full ring-1   ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                                     md:w-full 
                                     xl:w-8/12
                                     3xl:w-6/12'
                        type='text'
                        name='avgCurrSalary'
                        id='avgCurrSalary'
                        placeholder='متوسط درآمد ماهیانه فعلی'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('avgCurrSalary')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.avgCurrSalary ?(formik.errors.avgCurrSalary ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.avgCurrSalary}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label className='text-sm font-bold'>
                        کدامیک از موارد زیر را انتخاب می کنید؟
                    </label>
                    <div className='flex flex-col ga  items-center
                                    lg:max-3xl:items-start'>
                        <div className='flex gap-1 '>
                            <label>
                                نمایندگی فروش
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type='radio'
                                name='type'
                                value="نمایندگی فروش"
                                onChange={formik.getFieldProps("type").onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex gap-1 '>
                            <label>
                                عاملیت فروش 
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type='radio'
                                name='type'
                                value="عاملیت فروش"
                                onChange={formik.getFieldProps("type").onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex gap-1'>
                            <label>
                               همکاری
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type='radio'
                                name='type'
                                value="همکاری"
                                onChange={formik.getFieldProps("type").onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex gap-1 '>
                            <label>
                                سرمایه گذاری
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type='radio'
                                name='type'
                                value="سرمایه گذاری"
                                checked={formik.type ==="سرمایه گذاری"}
                                onChange={formik.getFieldProps("type").onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center
                                md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-1 md:items-center'>
                    <label>
                        توضیحات بیشتر:
                    </label>
                    <textarea 
                        className='block rounded-md p-5 w-full ring-1 placeholder:py-2 focus:text-sm  ring-gray-500 placeholder:text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 border-0  text-center text-black focus:outline-gray-500
                        md:w-full md:text-center md:p-10
                        lg:max-3xl:p-10 
                        xl:w-8/12
                        3xl:w-6/12'
                        name='aboutYou'
                        id='aboutYou'
                        placeholder='ما را با خود بیشتر آشنا کنید'
                        {...formik.getFieldProps('aboutYou')}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.aboutYou ?(formik.errors.aboutYou ? <div>
                                                                    <p className='text-red-500 lg:max-3xl:text-sm'>{formik.errors.aboutYou}</p>
                                                              </div> : null) : null}
                </div>
                <div className='flex items-center justify-center py-3 
                        lg:max-3xl:pb-10'>
                    <button 
                        className='w-full rounded-md p-2 text-center focus:shadow-md focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 self-center
                                md:w-4/12 
                                xl:max-2xl:w-2/12
                                3xl:w-1/12
                                '
                        title='ثبت'
                        type="submit"
                        >
                        ثبت
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='lg:col-span-2 lg:max-3xl:px-1'>
                <img
                    src={logo}
                    alt="لوگوی رادین"
                    className='w-0 h-0
                            lg:w-full lg:h-full 
                            xl:w-full xl:h-full '
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}


export default Bform
```

i tried using `handleReset()` and `resetForm()` but it didn't work.
i managed to solve it with using 4 states for each radio,but idon't like the idea of it and i want to find a better solution,because i have another form with more radio buttons.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).